# A calendar app that shows different projects side by side in columns?

Tags: macos, ios, applications, software-recommendation, calendar

I want to find an app (preferably for OSX and iOS) that shows all my different project calendars side by side in columns.

For several years now, I've been using a spreadsheet: Every row is one day, every column is a different project - or sometimes the personal calendar of one person that just shows on which days he's available (a bit like in Doodle).

It serves me, but it's not the easiest thing to use - simply because it's just a spreadsheet.

Does anyone know if there is an app where I could add, say, ten different projects and a hundred personal "free/busy" -calendars - and view any number of them side by side?

I don't need times of day, just the whole day on each row. I don't need to see any "project phases" and their "durations". I don't need these fancy project planners that the internet is full of. They don't serve the purpose at all.